# Login not redirecting properly

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a login on a website where it connects to the database, checks against it, but the redirect isn't working (login.php to loggedin.php). I am appalling at proof reading my own code and have been going round in circles for a while. If someone could assist I would be very grateful! Thank you in advance.

Login_page.inc.php

```
<?php # Script 11.1 - login_page.inc.php

// this page prints any errors associated with logging in
//and creates te entire login page, including the fom

//include the header:

$page_title = 'Login';

include ('includes/header.html');

//print any error messages if they exist:

if (!empty($errors)) 
{
echo '<h1>Error!</h1>

<p class="error">The following error(s) occurred:</br>';
foreach ($errors as $msg)
    {
    echo "- $msg</br>\n";
    }
echo '</p><p>Please try again.</p>';
}

//display form
?>
<h1>Login</h1>

    <form action=login.php" method="post">

        <p>Email Address: <input type="text" name="email" size="20" maxlength="80"/></p>

        <p>Password: <input type="password" name="pass" size="20" maxlength="20"/></p>

        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/></p>

        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE"/>

    </form>

<?php //include the footer:

include ('includes/footer.html');

?>
```

Loggedin.php

```
<?php # loggedin.php

//this is where the user is directed from login.php
session_start(); 
//if no cookie is present redirect the user:
//if (!isset($_COOKIE['user_id']))
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    //the functions need to create an absolute url
    require_once ('includes/login_functions.inc.php');

    $url = absolute_url();
    header("Location: $url");
    exit(); //exit script
}

//set the page title and include the header
$page_title = 'Logged in.';
include ('includes/header.html');

//welcome message
echo "<h1>Logged in!</h1>
<p>You have successfully logged in, {$_SESSION['first_name']}!</p>

<p><a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a></p>";

include ('includes/footer.html');

?>
```

Login.php

```
<?php # login.php
//this page processes the login form submission
//upon successful login the user's redirected
//two include files are needed for this
//send nothing to the web browser prior  to the setcookie() lines

//check if  the form has been submitted:
if (isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
    //for processing the login:
    require_once ('includes/login_functions.inc.php');

    //need the database connection:
    require_once ('includes/mysqli_connect.php');

    //check the login
    list ($check, $data) = check_login($dbc, $_POST['email'], $_POST['pass']);

    if($check)
    {
        /*ok, set cookies to last one hour after it is set
        setcookie ('user_id', $data ['user_id'], time()+3600, '/', '', 0, 0);

        setcookie ('first_name', $data ['first_name'], time()+3600, '/', '', 0, 0);*/

        session_start();

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $data['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $data['first_name'];

        //redirect
        $url = absolute_url ('loggedin.php');
        header("Location: $url");
        exit(); //quit the script 
    }

    else
    {
        //assign errors to $data for error reporting in the login_page.inc.php
        $errors = $data;
    }

    mysqli_close($dbc); //close the database connection
} //end of main submit condition

include ('includes/login_page.inc.php');



?>
```

Login_functions.php

```
<?php #- login_functions.inc.php

//this page defines two functions used by the login/logout process.

/*this function determines and returns an absolte URL
*takes one argument: the page that concludes the URL
*the arguement defaults to index.php
*/

function absolute_url ($page = 'index.php')
{

//start defining the URL. . .

//URL is http:// plus the host name plus current directory:

$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

//remove any trailing slashes:
$url = rtrim($url, '/\\');

//adding the page. . .
$url.= '/' . $page;

//return to the url
return $url;

} //end of the absolute_url function

/* this function validates the form data (the email address and password)

*if both are present the database is queried

*this function requires a database connection

* the function returns an array of information. including:

* - a TRUE or FALSE variable indicating a success or failure
* - an array of either errors or the database return result

*/

function check_login($dbc, $email = '', $pass = '')
{
    $errors = array(); //starting error array

    //validate email address

    if (empty($email))
    {
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your email address.';
    }

    else
    {
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($email));
    }

    //validate the password

    if (empty($pass))
    {
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your password.';
    }

    else
    {
    $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($pass));
    }

    if (empty($errors))
    {
    /*if everything's okay

    *retrieve the user_id and the first_name for that
    *email+password combination:
    */

    $q = "SELECT user_id, first_name FROM site_users WHERE email='$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p')";

    $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); //run the query

    //check the result and making sure that both fields are in the same row
    if(mysqli_num_rows($r) ==1)
    {
    //fetch the record
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    //return true and the record:
    return array(true, $row);
    }

    else
    {
    //not a match
    $errors[] = 'The email address and password entered do not match those on file.';
    }

    }//end of empty($errors) IF.

    //return false and the errors:
    return array(false, $errors);
} //end of check_login() function

?>
```

Comment: and how exactly is not working? where do you want to redirect to ? main dir ? or loggedin.php?

Comment: Which redirect fails? The one inside `if ($check)`?  And have you verified that the output of `absolute_url()` is correct and valid?

Comment: loggedin.php is where I'm trying to get to.
When trying to redirect to loggedin it tells me the page doesn't exist. I keep looking through again and again, but can't see why it wouldn't.

Comment: Nobody's going to read your code. What did you try? Did you isolate the problem already?

Comment: In case they do, or can instantly see what I've done wrong is why it's there. I'm unsure of what's causing the actual problem, it won't redirect to logged in, I get a browser error saying the file isn't there.

Comment: Can you remove the "@" sign before mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) let me ssee if there any mySQL error  .. please also note that you are using pass=SHA1('$p') so the password would never be in plain text ....

Comment: The error has been sorted, the down votes are genius, when by people who clearly couldn't help. Thanks to everyone that did! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was within the SHA1 talking to the database, where by SHA1 is a (40) strong and the database was set to (20). An annoying issue but it has not been resolved. Var_dump was used to talk to the database to prove that the information being entered was correct, it did however show that the password held in the database was (20) and the password entered for login was (40).

Answer (score 1):

If any of the files contains any code that gets sent to the browser, PHP sends all the headers automatically. After the headers have been sent, you can no longer send new headers, and it drops your `Location:` header. PHP should be throwing a notice, look for it in your logs and/or set the correct `error_reporting` flags.

This includes newlines or spaces or whatever that is after an `?>` tag block.

Comment: Would that stop loggedin.php from being loaded? At the moment I get a 404 error upon attempting to login. I have had no such error from php. Relatively new to php.

Comment: Ah, relevant errors! It helps if you tell those, I was just guessing at what was happening. Are you sure both files are in the same case? Is the target url correct? Unix-like webservers tend to be case-sensitive

Comment: Sh*t, sorry! Just edited it, yes both login and loggedin are in the same directory folder.

Comment: same case: I meant like UPPERCASE or lowercase.

Comment: Try looking at the rendered source code, pull out the generated url for `login.php`. Does that url make sense? is the file actually at that location?

Comment: Okay that errors sorted, thanks for your help. =) Combination of little things wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your script from what i can see ... here but am not sure of the content of

`includes/header.html`
`index.php`

You need to also replace

`<form action=login.php" method="post">`

with

`<form action="login.php" method="post">`

If you can paste the error you are seeing .. maybe i can help you better

Thanks
:)

Comment: Well that was one of the issues (embarrassing, I'm bad at proof reading my own stuff). But I'm now getting an error saying the password and email don't match, when I'm sure they do (I've got phpmyadmin open and can see that they match).

Comment: I get "The following error(s) occurred:
- The email address and password entered do not match those on file." even though both the email and password are correct, I can see the database table where they're being matched from so I'm not sure what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Don't include any blank line before your header('Location: $url'). Because this prevents sending header and you are not able to get redirect to place where you want to be.